# Google Maps API disabled with minimal usage

Tags: api, google-maps

The google maps API has suddenly been disabled on one of our sites that launched a couple of weeks ago http://electriphobia.com/  The page is showing this message when it loads.

"Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about ..... etc etc"

I have investigated the usage statistics in my api console and it is only showing minimal usage http://i1240.photobucket.com/albums/gg483/jmo26/ScreenShot2012-04-27at113111AM.png

I have tried regenerating to the api key and implementing it but the same message still persists.

I can't find an email address to contact google about this, can anyone point me in the right direction to find a solution???

Comment: I'm having the same issue, no idea,can't find anything online..

Comment: after finding no explanation to it, just remove the key, it'll most likely work..

Comment: Did you solved your problem? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide a direct link to a page showing this error?  I did not see any page with a map after a few clicks on electriphobia.com

Additionally, be sure that you have authorized that domain for the key in the code console (see API Access -> referers).  If not, then Edit Allowed Referers.

Comment: There is no referers! Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the API key worked when I ran into this problem.

Comment: This will work up to a point, but with Version 3.7 (current as of a few days ago) some libraries require a key.