# Google Maps v3 - Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We're creating a google map using the standard:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<key_here>&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

but have started getting dreaded popup:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.

We've seen a lot of people online who've experienced this error but no one seems to have a clear solution.  Most of the time it just "goes away".

Does anyone know the root cause of this and how to get it resolved?

We only made 200+ requests today so it's not a quota issue.

And yes, the error goes away when we remove the API key, but we have a large call to action happening in a few days so want to make sure we don't trip anything up but not having an API key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API disabled with minimal usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353621/google-maps-api-disabled-with-minimal-usage)

Comment: @geocodezip that question only says to remove the api key which is not the solution, because one wants to monitor api usage on the site which needs a key

Comment: That isn't what I see in the accepted answer from Josh Livni of google.

Comment: @geocodezip the accepted answer says to check the allowed refers. They are set properly, regardless the API throws this error. So that answer does not answer the question of why the API throws the error when API access is enabled and referers are set properly. I created many javascript maps api sites before, so it is not my first time of doing this, but this is the first time I get this error even if everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact Google Product support.

Comment: @geocodezip any idea how to contact google support for this type of problem? I've been through their developer docs and can't find anything other than "post your question on StackOverflow".

Comment: I haven't had to do that, but have seen references posted both here and in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 group.  I think there is a "product forum" somewhere also that may provide this type of support.

Comment: @BrianV Did you solved your problem?

Comment: You ask for this kind of information on the Google Maps Product Support forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/maps